# Where is cvarrToMat declared?

Tags: c++, opencv

Seriously, which header do I frigging need to include?! Why is it so hard to mention the header in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cvarrtomat)? Gotta be the worst library ever.

Comment: If all else fails `grep` the header files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in core.hpp and in the cv:: namespace

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Was not entirely aware this is in the C++ part, as it is used to interface the "C" structure. Well I guess it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

btw in 2020, latest version of opencv repository, modules/core/src/matrix_c.cpp

Comment: That is not an include. That is where it is implemented. Also this is more of a comment, not a real answer.